# Input() function in Python is not working

Tags: python, input

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to compile a VERY simple code in Python (using Atom editor), and after I run this code:

```
name = input("Name:")
print(f"hello, {name}")
```

And after typing in any name (in this case I simply typed in `n`, I get this error message:

```
Name:n

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_name.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("Name:")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

I hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: This is inPython-2.x I assume? In Python-3.x this works fine.

Comment: I don't know... How can I check it? And also how to update it in Atom. LOVE if you could help

Comment: In Python-2.x `input(..)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(..))` so it evaluates the input as if it is a Python expression. But anyway, Python-2.x is no longer supported since January 1, 2020

Comment: well Python-3.x is not an "upgrade" of Python-2.x. The two are actually two different languages (that look quite similar). On a Linux system, you run Python-3.x with `$ python3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input` instead of input, because `input` runs `eval` on the input. (Only in python 2, in Python 3 input has the same behavior of raw_input and raw_input is removed)

What that means is that after getting your input, python would evaluate your input as if it was code.
Try entering `"3+2*5-2"` in the input and see the output.

(Note that writing something like:"x = 5" won't work, because `eval` just evaluates an expression, like y+3 (assuming `y` is defined) and it does not actually run the code)

(But really, you should use python 3 if you are just learning Python and you are not already used to python2)

Comment: FYI, this is an Atom related issue. I ran this on python 3.7, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you try the same but not using atom? (I am suspicious that Atom did not switch interpreter.)

Comment: Ok! Do you have any other recommendations for other good compilers for Atom (I'm doing cs50's course, so I have the IDE, but I also want to have a desktop based compiler like Atom)

Comment: You mean other code editors? you can use Visual Studio Code. But did it work? running the same code not from Atom?

Comment: Yes! I just ran it on Visual Studio Code, but I get the same error (because before I ran it on an IDE). I dowloaded everything!!! I don't know why but this exact piece of code DOESN'T work in my Visual Studio Code

Answer (score -1):

yes its right i also phase a problem like that and my code is

```
name = input("enter you name: ")
print(name)
```

so i enter my name **Anshu**
then it show this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/anshu/Projects/coding/python/dictnory_problem.py", line 6, in 
search = input("enter your keyword: ")
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'anshu' is not defined

then i change my code i use

```
name = raw-input("enter your name")
print(name)
```

Comment: sorry for that its raw_input

Comment: This is just saying the same as the accepted answer... with typos added.

Comment: ya you can say this but it work in condition